# List comprehension for extracting re.findall matches

Tags: python, regex, functional-programming, iterator, generator

I have a regular expression with a single group, and I want to use it to map a list of strings to a filtered list of matches for strings that match. Currently, I'm using the following:

```
matches = (re.findall(r'wh(at)ever', line) for line in lines)
matches = [m[0] for m in matches if m]
```

How can I do this more elegantly, using only filters, maps, and comprehensions? Obviously, I could use a for loop, but I wonder if it can be done purely by manipulating iterators.

Comment: You *are* only manipulating iterators here, are you just looking for a one-liner?

Comment: `matches = [m[0] for m in (re.findall(r'wh(at)ever', line) for line in lines) if m]`

Comment: You can `from functools import partial` and `from operator import itemgetter` and have the very functional `list(map(itemgetter(0), filter(None, map(partial(re.findall, r'wh(at)ever'), lines))))` ... but I still think your original construction is more elegant.

Comment: Why do you use `re.findall` if you only want the first item?

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Is there a better alternative? If so please tell me :)

Comment: @RenéG: with `re.search` that returns (and stops at) the first result: `[m.group(1) for m in (re.search(r'wh(at)ever', line) for line in lines) if m]`

Comment: @casmirethippolyte That will throw an exception of any strings don't match. You still have to check for None.

Comment: @RenéG: no it doesn't, since `m` is tested with `if m`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no real advantage obfuscating your code with map, filter, or other functional tricks since a list comprehension is fast, simple and clear:

```
import re

lines = ['wh1atever wh1btever', 'wh2atever', '', 'wh4atever wh4btever wh4ctever']

'''Since you only want the first item for each line,
   using re.findall is a waste of time, re.search is more appropriate'''

pat1 = re.compile(r'wh(..)tever')
res1 = [ m.group(1) for m in (pat1.search(line) for line in lines) if m ]

print(res1)
'''['1a', '2a', '4a']'''


'''or if there are few lines, you can join them and use re.findall this time,
   with a pattern that consumes the end of the line'''

pat2 = re.compile(r'wh(..)tever.*')
res2 = pat2.findall("\n".join(lines))

print(res2)
'''['1a', '2a', '4a']'''
```

Comment: I said "maps, filters, and comprehensions" :) I like this one best! I would put `m.group(1)` on one line, `for m in ()` on the next, and `if m` on a third.

Answer (score 1):

You can use maps and filters. Here's one way.

```
matches = map(lambda x: x[0], filter(None, map(lambda x: re.findall(r'wh(at)ever', x), lines)))
```

If you're using python3, don't forget to tack on a `list(...)` at the end.

However, I don't see much of a need for more "elegance" here. What you're doing is perfectly fine.

---

An alternative courtesy @juanpa.arrivillaga:

```
from functools import partial
list(map(itemgetter(0), filter(None, map(partial(re.findall, r'wh(at)ever'), lines))))
```

Comment: one line >>>>>> two lines

Comment: I think you can do simply `None` instead of `lambda x:x` for `filter`, it's beeen ages since I've actually use filter instead of a comprehension though

Comment: One line is often worse than two-lines. This is a great example.

Comment: @Coldspeed Also, this doesn't work. The result will be a list of singleton lists of strings, not a list of strings.

Comment: You're forgetting the last map: grab the first item from `findall`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Agreed, that's why I've added what OP's doing is good enough. :-)

Comment: Without `lambda`s: `list(map(itemgetter(0), filter(None, map(partial(re.findall, r'wh(at)ever'), lines))))`

Comment: @RenéG You do NOT want to use this solution if you're working with python2.

Comment: So this is basically what I'm doing, just in one line instead of across two. Is there any way to truly do it more elegantly?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga That's another great alternative. I've added your solution to my answer but let me know if you want me to take it out.

Comment: Nah, that's fine.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Quick question... what does the `partial(...)` do here?

Comment: It [partially applies the function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial). But yes, it is all going to be basically the same way. Just dressed up differently, and made less readable than your original version in all likelyhood.